# Is there a fast hashing algorithm which is resistant to deliberate collision, and if so, which one?

Tags: hash, cryptography, distribution, verification

I am developing an "open distributed cloud storage system".

By open I mean that anyone can participate in hosting of files.

My current design uses a sha1 hash of the files content as global file id.

It is given that the client already knows this hash value and receives the file from a "bandwidth donor".

The client now needs to verify that the file indeed is the correct one, by generating the hash and comparing it to the expected value.

However my concern is that someone could deliberately modify a file to produce the same hash. As far as I know this is doable easily for hashes of the CRC family. Some "googling" around revealed a lot of claims that the same would be easy for MD5.

Now my question is: Is there a  hashing algorithm which satisfies the criteria of beeing

- fast for big amounts of data
- well distributed in the hashing range (aka "unique")
- has a sufficient target range ("bit length")
- is resistant to deliberate collision attacks

All other means that I can think of achieving a setup that serves my needs involve a secret component, for example a secret openssl key or a shared secret salt for a hash function.

Unfortunately I cannot work with that.

Comment: What you want is a secure hash function. For your application, speed should most definitely be secondary to security - and bear in mind, hashing speed for a function such as SHA-1 or SHA-256 is going to be orders of magnitude faster than the speed a client can receive a file over a network connection anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is a one-way function, whose existence is a major open problem.

With cryptographic hash functions, the specific attack you wanted to avoid is called the "second pre-image attack".

That should help you Googling what you want, but as far as I know there is actually no known practical second pre-image attack for MD5.

First of all, you probably found that it is easy to find two arbitrary files that have the same hash, and to find two different such pairs every time you try.

But it is difficult to generate a file to disguise as some specific file - in other words, it is unlikely that one of the prementioned "two arbitrary files" actually belongs to a non-malicious agent in your storage.

If you're still not satisfied, you might want to try something like SHA-1 or SHA-2 or GOST.

Comment: Yes, there are no known attacks against MD5. But the latest researches are too close to this. It's strongly not recommended to use MD5 in security sphere. GOST (34311) is not good choice too.

Comment: Indeed. Why on earth would you pick MD5 for a new application now, when there are so many better solutions available?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, a hash value can never identify a file, as there will always be collisions.

Having said that, what you are looking for is called a [cryptographic hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash). These are designed to not (easily, i.e. other than brute force) allow modifications of the data while keeping the hash, or producing new data with a given hash.

As such, the SHA family is ok.

Comment: A hash certainly can identify a file. You might just as well argue an airplane can't be used to travel because it might crash. *Everything* we do has possible failure modes.

Answer (score 2):

For the moment, SHA1 is adequate. No collisions are known.

It would help a lot to know the average size of the thing you are hashing. But most likely, if your platforms are predominantly 64-bit, SHA512 is your best choice. You can truncate the hash and use only 256-bits of it. If your platforms are predominantly 32-bit, SHA256 is your best choice.